# Multiple CheckBox Validation using spring JS?

Tags: validation, checkbox, dojo, spring-js

I am creating dynamic Check Boxes in runtime. my requirement is have to validate atleast one checkbox checked or not. am doing this using springJS. But to validate i have to pass checkBox Id to spring Validation, But this ID array creating in   runtime. how can i achieve this? i tried all solutions but it did'nt worked for me. i am doing like this it was working if i hardcode checkbox id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Spring.addDecoration(
        new Spring.ElementDecoration({
            elementId: '_CheckBox_ids',
            widgetType: 'dijit.form.CheckBox',
            widgetModule: 'dijit.form.CheckBox',
            validate: function () {
                if (dojo.query("#roo_apiUser_profile > input[type=checkbox]", 'dijit.form').filter(function (n) {
                    return n.checked;
                }).length > 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert('choose at least one profile');
                    return false;
                }
            },
            widgetAttrs: {
                required: true
            }
        }));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add the `onsubmit` attribute in your [form](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.form) tag and call a function that does the validation on checkboxes.

Alternately, you may create your own extension of `AbstractElementDecoration` (defined in `spring.js`) using `dojo.declare` and pass to the `validate` attribute a function that will do the checkboxes validation for you. For `elementId` you may pass in the `id` of a `div` element that contains all the checkboxes. `Spring.ValidateAllDecoration` calls `Spring.validateAll` function. Make sure you do the necessary tweaking in your `AbstractElementDecoration` extension so that there is no exceptions in `Spring.validateAll`.